# Function to filter a list of strings in scala

Tags: list, scala

I am only beggining programming in Scala or functional programming. I was supposed to write a function that would filter a list of strings (the first line of main was given in the exercise). It is supposed to return words "Hello people". I have managed it with using variable but my teacher told me to modify it to not use any var. I've been trying to do that but I have no idea why the code below keeps returning an error. I'd appreciate any help because I am stumped.

```
main.scala:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: List[String]
      if(filter(workList.head))
      ^
1 error
exit status 1
```

```
object Main {
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(filterList(List("Hello", "there", "people"), _.contains('l')).mkString(" "))
}

  def filterList(listToSort:List[String], filter: (String) => Boolean): List[String] = {
  
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recFilter(workList: List[String], filteredList: List[String]): List[String] = {
      if(workList.isEmpty)
        return filteredList
      if(filter(workList.head))
        recFilter(workList.tail, workList.head :: filteredList)
    }

    return recFilter(listToSort, List())
  }
  
}
```

Comment: 1 - Don't use `return`. It's bad form and will lead you astray. 2 - Every `if` should have an `else`. In fact, if you don't supply an `else` then the compiler will supply one for you. That's where your error is coming from. An `if` with a default `else` is an expression that evaluates to `Unit`.

Comment: Use pattern matching instead of calling `ifEmpty` / `had` & `tail`

Comment: @jwvh Thank you, it really was problem with missing `else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the parameters of the excercise are, but the standard collections library in scala can do quite a bit for you...

In this case, List actually has a filter method already...

```
List("Hello", "there", "people").filter(_.contains("l"))
```

It may be worth skimming through tab completion on such a list and reading the docs on the suggestions.

If the excercise is to write your own, then obviously, this isn't the most helpful answer ever, and apologies for that. Another idea might be something like this;

```
def filterList(aList: List[String]) = {
  for (
    word <- aList
    if word.contains("l")
  ) yield {
    word
  }
}

val filtered = filterList(testList)
```

Which is an intro to for yield syntax...

Comment: Yes, we had to write our own  filtering function. I accualy had `yield` before, I haven't even thought about using it in that example. Thank you for helping me to look at this problem in another light

Comment: Cool - hope you have fun with Scala… my personal preference is for readability above other concerns. One idea may be to present a bouquet of solutions and look back in a few months. My personal preferred solution would be the easiest to understand one your memory of the task had faded…

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using a recursion with a helper function and pattern matching.

```
def filterList(xs: List[String], filter: String => Boolean): List[String] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def filterListR(xs: List[String], filter: String => Boolean, acc: List[String]): List[String] = xs match{
    case Nil                         => acc
    case head::tail if(filter(head)) => filterListR(tail, filter, head :: acc)
    case head::tail                  => filterListR(tail, filter, acc)
  }
  filterListR(xs, filter, List[String]()).reverse
}
```

Output:

```
scala> filterList(List("Hello", "there", "people"), (s: String) => s.contains("l"))
val res3: List[String] = List(Hello, people)
```